# JavaScript Function to increment ending string value and retain leading zeros

Tags: javascript, string, function

I am fairly new to programming and have been teaching myself JavaScript over the course of the last couple weeks. Using various resources such as Lynda.com, codewars, and other miscellaneous resources. I recently participated in a challenge on codewars and finally solved one that I had been having difficulty with for days myself for which I am very proud... I, however, would like to present this solution to you and explain it's function to you so that maybe ya'll as a community could critique it in terms of best practices and what I could have done differently to simplify the solution... Like I said, I'm still very new to this so I apologize if the solution seems overly bloated and elementary. Thank you for your consideration and time!

So I was tasked with writing a function that accepts a string, tests it for numbers. If there is a number it is supposed to increment the number in the string and if there isn't or aren't any numbers it is supposed to append the number 1 to the end of the string. I appreciate all and any feedback on this, thank you!

```
    function incrementString (strng) {
       // Declare variables
       var findNum = strng.search(/[0-9]/);
       var findLetters = strng.slice(0, findNum);
       var numContainer = strng.slice(findNum);
       var numContainerConversion = parseInt(numContainer);
       // Increment number string conversion
       numContainerConversion++;
       // Check whether number search finds a match, if not, return string 
       //with 1 appended 
       if(findNum < 0) {
         return strng += 1;
       } else if(findNum >= 0) { //If number search finds a match, increment 
       //number and reappend to original string 
       numContainerConversion += "";
       var numLength = numContainer.length;
       var numContainerLength = numContainerConversion.length;
       //For Loop that adds zero padding as the number conversion strip 
       //original padding
       for(var i = numContainerLength; numContainerLength < numLength; 
       numContainerLength++) {
       findLetters += "0"
       }
       return findLetters + numContainerConversion;
      }
     return numContainerConversion;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Brice! Welcome to programming. :) Unfortunately this site isn't meant to be used for feedback sessions, as outlined here: [Dont ask if...] *"- there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”* (https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - if your solution isn't working, than your question would be appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that a little after I posted this... thanks for the response. Have a good one, I'll remember not to post unless I'm actually asking for help with something. I appreciate it

Comment: No problem :) Cheers!